# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in asp

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect, response.redirect

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Member E = new Member();
    E = E.Login(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    Session["user"] = E;
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        E = (Member)Session["user"];
        if (E.UserType == "Doctor")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Donate.aspx");
        }
        else if (E.UserType == "admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
        }
    }
    else

    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Email / password";
    }    
}
}
```

this is login

```
public Member Login(string Email, string Password)
{
    string constr = "Data Source = YAZAN-PC ; initial catalog = Aged ; user = sa; pwd = yazan7;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Authenticate", conn);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        return new Member
ID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString()),
            FName = dt.Rows[0]["FName"].ToString(),
            LName = dt.Rows[0]["LName"].ToString(),
            Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(),         
            Gender = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString(),
            Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString(),
            RePassword = dt.Rows[0]["RePassword"].ToString(),
            UserType = dt.Rows[0]["UserType"].ToString(),
            BirthDate = dt.Rows[0]["BirthDate"].ToString(),
```

this is the class

i have 3 users 
Doctor
admin 
Family
i need when the user login 
if he is a doctor redirect to page (doctor.aspx) else
if he is an admin  redirect to page (admin.aspx)
how to do it using session????

Comment: What are you storing in the session?

Comment: Please show some code as to how you are currently returning info about a user when they login.

Comment: i but the code will u show it plz

Comment: Please show your code for Login().

Comment: i add the code on my login page and on my class @sr28

Comment: Are you missing some brackets around your properties for 'Member'? I doubt this code would compile at the moment.

Comment: the brackets correct it's given the error when i run login page and try to login with the email and password i save in database @sr28

Comment: You must be missing some code as what you've pasted for the Login method wouldn't compile. The last line I see is the one starting with 'BirthDate'.

Comment: thank u @sr28 it's work sorry if i take from ur time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a login class..

```
class dcLogin
{
public id string{get;set;}
public name string{get;set;}
public type string{get;set;}
}
```

when user logging in then..
set

```
dcLogin  objLog=new dcLogin(); 
objLog.id=userid; objLog.name=username; 
objLog.type='usertype'--admin/doctor/user

session["loginuser"]=objLog;
```

now you can check user type any time.

```
dcLogin  objLog=(dcLogin)session["loginuser"];
if(objLog.type=="admin")
{
response.redirect("admin.aspx");
}
```

Edit2:
create a common home page after login.

```
loginhome.aspx

protected void page_lod()
{
 if(session["user"]!=null)
 {
   Member E=(Member)session["user"];
if(E.UserType =="Doctor")
{
  response.rediter("doctor.aspx");
}
else if(E.UserType =="admin")
{
  response.rediter("admin.aspx");
}
else
{
 response.rediter("user.aspx");
} 
}
}
```

Comment: @YazanTamimi see Edit2

Comment: Thank You 
i will test it and i will tell what will happen with me 
thanks again

Comment: It;s given me Error it's says
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
it's given me the highlight on the if statment

Comment: I have to write this code on the page load or on my button click function??

Comment: did you use session["user"] ??i missed it on my code.

Comment: in page_lod of the common 'login loginhome.aspx' home page.

Comment: fist of all thank u for ur time 
i write like what u sai it's given me error on the email i use email and pass to login but now it's not working

Comment: Google the error you'll find solution yourself. @YazanTamimi

Comment: yes still not it's still given me invalid email i checked the database the email and password are saved correctly when i try to login it's not login @user3540365

Comment: Invalid email / password that's is the error it's shown when i press the login button @user3650365

Comment: i solve it but now when it's loged in it's not redirect me on any page it's given me ""The resource cannot be found."" @user3540365

Comment: thank u alooot @user3540365 it's work i'm sorry if i take from ur time

Comment: hhhhhh yes finally thank u for ur effort with me @user3540365

Comment: i try to add another question but it's not added i need to program an donate page in asp that let user to donate can u help me?? @user3540365

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're storing in the session, you can use that to retrieve the data about the user. Since you're not provided any code or logic to how you want to perform these actions, I am going to take a guess.

1. Retrieve value from the session (Say the user id)
2. Use that id from the session to fetch the user data from the database or list
3. With the data returned, get the "rank" / "privileged" value, so say doctor is 1, family is 2, users is 3
4. Do a switch on the rank and depending on if it's 1, 2 or 3, redirect accordingly.

Hopes this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're getting the error because the session is null. I can't believe your login code compiles as you're line 'return new member' followed by lines of property setting isn't correct. However, that aside I would suggest that your problem is caused by your Login method.

I'd write it like this:

```
public Member Login(string Email, string Password)
{
    string constr = "Data Source = YAZAN-PC ; initial catalog = Aged ; user = sa; pwd = yazan7;";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Authenticate", conn);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    Member m = new Member();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Set member properties
        m.ID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
        m.FName = dt.Rows[0]["FName"].ToString();
        m.LName = dt.Rows[0]["LName"].ToString();
        m.Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();         
        m.Gender = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
        m.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
        m.RePassword = dt.Rows[0]["RePassword"].ToString();
        m.UserType = dt.Rows[0]["UserType"].ToString();
        m.BirthDate = dt.Rows[0]["BirthDate"].ToString();

        //add any other properties needed to be filled.
    }

    return m;
}
```

You would then use the 'UserType' as per your current code. Depending on the values you can have for 'UserType' will depend on what you check for. If you have values like 'Doctor' then you might want to make sure you are trimming white space and that your check isn't case sensitive such as:

```
if (E.UserType.Trim().Equals("Doctor", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Response.Redirect("Donate.aspx");
}
```